# ReturnURL does not contain the defaultURL file

Tags: web-config, asp.net-membership, returnurl

I am trying to determine why I am having an issue with forms authentication in my application.  Specifically the ReturnURL parameters.  I expect my URL to look like this      `"http://www.example.com/ApplicationName/login.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fApplicationDirectory%2ListImages.aspx"` when I browse to the address 
`"http://www.example.com/ApplicationName"`.

Web.Config contains

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="ListImages.aspx" name=".WebDashboardAuth" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The URL created is instead `"http://www.example.com/ApplicationName/login.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fApplicationDirectory%2"` and does not show the defaultURL file.

What could be wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

`defaultUrl` parameter in your `Web.Config` is the path that will be accessed if there is no `ReturnURL` in the `Querystring`. It won't be passed as a `Querystring`.

The `ReturnURL` in the `Querystring` can be what you expect if an non-authenticated user would go to `http://www.mydomain.com/ApplicationName/ListImages.aspx`, then thrown back to the `Login.aspx`. Only then will the `ReturnURL` have a path.